# Hibernate JPA 2.1: OUT REF CURSOR in position other than first?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures

I'm working with a legacy Oracle database where all of the stored procedures are defined with the OUT parameter *last*. Hibernate only supports stored procedures with the OUT parameter defined *first*.

Using Hibernate ORM 4.3.5, is there a way to override Hibernate's Oracle driver to use the *last* parameter instead of the *first* for getting the value from a `@NamedNativeQuery`? I've started down the path of using `CallableStatement`, but that defeats the whole purpose of using Hibernate and JPA.

Here's how I've attempted to define my `@NamedNativeQuery`, and I'd like to stick with this definition if possible:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "MyEntity.storedProc",
    query = "call ENTITY_PKG.StoredProc(:inputOne, :inputTwo, :resultSet)",
    callable = true,
    readOnly = true,
    resultClass = MyEntity.class
)
```

---

**UPDATED:**

After following up on Neil Stockton's answer, I came up with the following `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` annotation:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name = "MyEntity.storedProc",
        procedureName = "ENTITY_PKG.StoredProc",
        resultClasses = MyEntity.class,
        parameters = {
            @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "I_INPUT_ONE", type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.IN),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "I_INPUT_TWO", type = Character.class, mode = ParameterMode.IN),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "O_CURSOR", type = void.class, mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR)
        }
)
```

However, using the above results in this exception... `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect does not support resultsets via stored procedures`. Here's the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect does not support resultsets via stored procedures
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.registerResultSetOutParameter(Dialect.java:1612)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.cursor.internal.StandardRefCursorSupport.registerRefCursorParameter(StandardRefCursorSupport.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.prepare(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:417)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.outputs(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:234)
    at com.example.MyEntityDao.testStoredProc(MyEntityDao.java:88)
```

That occurs when I attempt to execute the query like this:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager
        .createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("MyEntity.storedProc");

query.setParameter("I_INPUT_ONE", "inputOneValue");
query.setParameter("I_INPUT_TWO", 'x');
query.execute(); // exception is triggered by query.execute()

MyEntity myEntity = (MyEntity) query.getOutputParameterValue("O_CURSOR");
```

This doesn't make a whole lot of sense in itself, because `Oracle10gDialect` *does* inherit an implementation of `registerResultSetOutParameter()`. This method is `@Override`n by `Oracle8iDialect`, which is a superclass of `Oracle9iDialect`, which in turn is a superclass of `Oracle10gDialect`.

My Hibernate dialect is defined in the `<properties>` section of `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
```

For reference, this is the spec of my stored procedure... The body has no `RETURN`, so the `OUT` cursor is the only way I have of accessing the result.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ENTITY_PKG IS
TYPE EntityCursor IS REF CURSOR;

PROCEDURE StoredProc
(
   I_INPUT_ONE IN ENTITIES.INPUT_ONE%TYPE, -- VARCHAR2
   I_INPUT_TWO IN ENTITIES.INPUT_TWO%TYPE, -- CHAR
   O_CURSOR OUT EntityCursor 
);

END ENTITY_PKG;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oracle does not directly support stored procedures that return ResultSet, but there is a workaround. Reference [here](http://blog.harpoontech.com/2013/05/using-oracle-stored-procedures-and-java.html). HTH

Answer (score 1):

JPA 2.1 provides an API to use Stored Procedures rather than hacking them through as a native "query". Perhaps you really ought to use that?

Comment: Using JPA 2.1, Hibernate 5.0.9, Oracle10gDialect - I CAN NOT get the Stored procedures API to work with named parameters and at least one OUT paramters. Positional seems ok, but just putting the warning out there.

Comment: perhaps you ought to add your own question with details of your problem, since this was targetted to someone else's

Comment: I tried with StoredProcedureQuery but getting same exception, so issue is not using JPA 2.1